# Cell Fracture adding unintentional items to object

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I'm trying to use the Cell Fracture add-on in Cycles Render to shatter a wine glass. The final product had added "blocks" onto the final object.

Does anyone know what could be causing this and how to fix it??

Original:[image]

Shattered Object:
[image]

Comment: Make sure glass object is [manifold](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7910/what-is-non-manifold-geometry) before fracturing it (especially in the place where unexpected geometry appears)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because your "wine glass" has no volume in some parts. The brim of the glass is infinitely thin. How can something like that be fractured?

Try adding some thickness to your model first before doing your spin extrusion (if that's how you made this).

Comment: Thanks for you help. Thickening it alone didn't fix it, but making sure it was manifold as @MrZak suggested was the other thing that helped fix it.

Comment: Glad it worked out for you! :-)